# all site content suddenly left-justified

Tags: html, css

When I edited the HTML for one page, all of the site pages were left-justified such that there's a huge space to the right. When I checked the CSS code, all div tags are positioned using 'auto'. Importantly, this happened to html/css that I didn't even edit. Here's my CSS:

```
/* CSS Document  - this does formatting for you*/

/* Erice Myer's Reset, which resets the browser's innate styles to a baseline */

html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border 0: background: transparent; font-size: 12px;}

div, span, article, aside, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, a, ol, ul, li, table, tr, th, td, tbody, tfoot, thead {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
    }

img {margin: 0; padding; 0; border: 0; }

table, tr, th, td, tbody, tfoot, thead {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    }

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0 }

input, select, textarea, form, fieldset {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border 0;
    }

article, aside, dialog, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display:block; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, blockquote, td, th, a, caption, em, strong, strike {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    }

ol, ul { list-style: none; }
/* Reset ends and my style starts below */

/* Global - specify properties for the whole page*/
html    { }
body    { background-color:#666}

/* Headings - specify properties for headers*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hbar1, hbar2, hbar3, hbar4, hbar5, hbar6 {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
/* Headers with gray bars */
hbar1 {font-size:24px; color:#F60; padding-bottom:10px; border-bottom:2px #CCC solid; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom:15px;}
hbar2 {font-size:24px; color:#000; padding-bottom:10px; border-bottom:2px #CCC solid; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom:15px;}
hbar3 {font-size:20px; color:#F60; padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom:2px #CCC solid; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom:15px;}
hbar4 {font-size:20px; color:#000; padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom:2px #CCC solid; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom:15px;}
hbar5 {font-size:16px; color:#F60; padding-bottom:0px; border-bottom:2px #CCC solid; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom:15px;}
hbar6 {font-size:16px; color:#000; padding-bottom:0px; border-bottom:2px #CCC solid; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom:15px;}
/* Headers without bars */
h1 {font-size:24px; color:#F60; padding-bottom:10px;}
h2 {font-size:24px; color:#000; padding-bottom:10px;}
h3 {font-size:20px; color:#F60; padding-bottom:5px;}
h4 {font-size:20px; color:#000; padding-bottom:5px;}
h5 {font-size:16px; color:#F60; padding-bottom:0px;}
h6 {font-size:16px; color:#000; padding-bottom:0px;}

/* Text Elements - specify properties for inner content text */
/* normal text */
p           { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size: 12px; line-height:150%; margin:5px 0; margin-top:15px}
p .left     { float:left;}
p .right    { float:right;}

/*anchors for links*/
a           {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px}
a:link      { color:#000; }
a:visited   { color:#000; }
a:active    { color:#000; }
a:focus     { color:#F60; }
a:hover     { color:#F60; }

a12             {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;} 
a12:link        { color:#000;}
a12:visited     { color:#666;}
a12:active      { color:#000;}
a12:focus       { color:#F60;}
a12:hover       { color:#F60;}


/* Image */
img         { }
.image_people       {float:left; margin-top:25px; margin-left:150px}

/* Containers - set size of stuff
    margin: 2 values (top,left) (top, right) (bottom, right) 
    (bottom, left) going clockwise.  auto sets it to be       
    centered
    float: allows things to be floated and justified 
    clear: says don't allow something float up in somewhere else
    margin/padding: margin spaces outside and padding spaces inside
    */
/* Formatting for header/banner for each page */
#outer { width: 960px; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:30px; margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px; background-color:#FFF; }
#wrapper { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; background-color:#FFF; }
#lab_logo { margin: 30px 0px; float:left; background-color:#FFF; }
#icons { margin: 35px 0px; float:right; }
#top_nav            { clear:both; } /* below are descendent selectors for top nav */
#top_nav ul         { border-top:2px #000 solid; border-bottom:2px #000 solid; margin:10px 0; padding:5px 0;}
#top_nav ul li      { display:inline; }
#top_nav ul li a    { padding:0 10px;   }
#banner { margin-bottom:-10px; }

/* Formatting for top */
#content_top                { margin: 30px 0px; width:900px;    float:left; }
#content_top p              { } /* paragraph style */
#content_top a              { line-height:150%;  margin-top:15px} /* anchor link style */
#content_top a:link         { color:#000; font-size:12px; }
#content_top a:visited      { color:#000; font-size:12px; }
#content_top a:active       { color:#000; font-size:12px; }
#content_top a:focus        { color:#F60; font-size:12px; }
#content_top a:hover        { color:#F60; font-size:12px; }
#content ul li              { margin-left: 30px;}
#content_top h1             { font-size:24px; color:#F60; }
#content_top h2             { font-size:24px; color:#000; }
#content_top h3             { font-size:20px; color:#F60; }
#content_top h4             { font-size:20px; color:#000; }
#content_top h5             { font-size:16px; color:#F60; }
#content_top h6             { font-size:16px; color:#000; }
#content_top hbar1      {font-size:24px; color:#F60; }
#content_top hbar2      {font-size:24px; color:#000; }
#content_top hbar3      {font-size:20px; color:#F60; }
#content_top hbar4      {font-size:20px; color:#000; }
#content_top hbar3      {font-size:16px; color:#F60; }
#content_top hbar4      {font-size:16px; color:#000; }

/* Formatting for middle left justified*/
#content                { margin: 30px 0 ; width:900px; float:left; }
#content p              { } /* paragraph style */
#content p_right        {float:left}
#content a              { float:left} /* anchor link style */
#content a:link         { color:#000; font-size:24px; margin-top:120px; margin-left:50px}
#content a:visited      { color:#000; font-size:24px; }
#content a:active       { color:#000; font-size:24px; }
#content a:focus        { color:#F60; font-size:24px; }
#content a:hover        { color:#F60; font-size:24px; }
#content h1             { font-size:24px; color:#F60; }
#content h2             { font-size:24px; color:#000; }
#content h3             { font-size:20px; color:#F60; }
#content h4             { font-size:20px; color:#000; }
#content h5             { font-size:16px; color:#F60; }
#content h6             { font-size:16px; color:#000; }
#content hbar1      {font-size:24px; color:#F60; }
#content hbar2      {font-size:24px; color:#000; }
#content hbar3      {font-size:20px; color:#F60; }
#content hbar4      {font-size:20px; color:#000; }
#content hbar3      {font-size:16px; color:#F60; }
#content hbar4      {font-size:16px; color:#000; }

/* Formatting for bottom */
#content_bottom                 { margin: 30px 0 ; width:900px; float:left; }
#content_bottom p               { } /* paragraph style */
#content_bottom a               { } /* anchor link style */
#content_bottom a:link          { color:#000; font-size:12px; }
#content_bottom a:visited       { color:#000; font-size:12px; }
#content_bottom a:active        { color:#000; font-size:12px; }
#content_bottom a:focus     { color:#F60; font-size:12px; }
#content_bottom a:hover     { color:#F60; font-size:12px; }
#content_bottom h1          { font-size:24px; color:#F60; }
#content_bottom h2          { font-size:24px; color:#000; }
#content_bottom h3          { font-size:20px; color:#F60; }
#content_bottom h4          { font-size:20px; color:#000; }
#content_bottom h5          { font-size:16px; color:#F60; }
#content_bottom h6          { font-size:16px; color:#000; }
#content_bottom hbar1       {font-size:24px; color:#F60; }
#content_bottom hbar2       {font-size:24px; color:#000; }
#content_bottom hbar3       {font-size:20px; color:#F60; }
#content_bottom hbar4       {font-size:20px; color:#000; }
#content_bottom hbar3       {font-size:16px; color:#F60; }
#content_bottom hbar4       {font-size:16px; color:#000; }

/* Formatting for bottom */
#footer {clear: both; margin:30px 0; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; border-top: 2px #000 solid; border-top: 2px #000 solid; background-color:#FFF}
#footer p { text-align:center; }
/* Micellaneous */
.date       {color:#F60; margin-bottom:1px; margin-top:15px}
```

**REVISION: Please go here to access HTML as well: https://jsfiddle.net/9m4umcrc/**

Comment: What does your html look like?  Can you add a fiddle that demomstrates the problem?

Comment: Keep an eye out for missing HTML tag (maybe closing tag).

Comment: Use your developer tools in the browser, it will tell you exactly what CSS rules are being applied.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Krista. Unfortunately, we need to see the HTML as well, otherwise we can only provide pure speculation. Without the HTML added to your question, it risks being closed as Off-Topic with the reason "Questions asking to solve a problem must include enough code to verify and reproduce the problem".

Comment: Is the problem that the white area isn't centered in the grey area?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is a typo or not. But by any chance while you were fiddling with the css did u happen to change this line ?

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border 0: background: transparent; font-size: 12px;}
```

because if you look closely, the part where it says
 `border 0: background: transparent;`
 seems wrong it should be `border: 0; background: transparent;`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! I'm sure that it's useful to correct, but it doesn't seem to fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

The outer div is set to a margin of 30px.  Perhaps you needed this on another page and changing it changed the layout of this page.

https://jsfiddle.net/9m4umcrc/2/

Change:

```
#outer { width: 960px; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:30px; margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px; background-color:#FFF; }
```

To:

```
#outer { width: 960px; margin:30px auto; background-color:#FFF; }
```

But, I suspect you'll have issues on other pages if you do this, so check your shared css.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your patience with my naïveté. That was a workable solution.